# Ошибки при подключении node к react, как избавиться?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Ошибки:
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**
**GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N9BL6zL 404 (Not Found)**

server.js:

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// data base
const rooms = new Map();

// rooms
app.get('/rooms', (req, res) => {
    res.json(rooms);
});

// connection
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected', socket.id);
});

// server
app.listen(8000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw Error(err)
    }
    console.log('Server started!');
});
```

App.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import JoinBlock from './components/joinBlock.jsx';
import socket from './socket';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <JoinBlock socket={socket} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

socket.js:

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io();
 
export default socket;
```

В package.json добавил - "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"

joinBlock.jsx:

```js
import React from 'react';
import socket from '../socket';

function JoinBlock() {
    return (
        <div className="join-block">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Room ID" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" />
            <button className="btn-success">ВОЙТИ</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default JoinBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io не будет работать с proxy, в `const socket = io(`) нужно явно указать, куда вы хотите подключаться `const socket = io('http://localhost:8000/')` это временное решение, если вы деплоите проект, то можно добавить переменную `ENDPOINT` и туда вносить данные о host-е на которым вы находитесь, если вы планируете, что сервер будет возвращать static, тогда можно будет оставить пустым.

Comment: Я проверял не работает

Comment: Попробуй поменять `server.listen(8000, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw Error(err)
    }
    console.log('Server started!');
});`